# JavaScript date&time conversion tz to normal

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, timezone

I am getting result in this TZ form my timezone is (Asia/Karachi GMT +5)

created_at:"2016-04-24T18:42:52Z"

but I want normal date and time 
in separate variable like

```
date = 2016-04-24
time = 06:42pm
```

from this tz data

my app is in nodejs
I tried moment (http://momentjs.com) module from npmjs but I want a simpler JavaScript way to convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what i want

```
var x = "2016-04-24T18:42:52Z" //var x = new Date();
var json = JSON.stringify(x);
var dateStr = JSON.parse(json);  
console.log(dateStr)
var datex = new Date(dateStr);
console.log(datex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want

```
new Date(new Date().getTime()).toLocaleDateString(); // 11/16/2015
new Date(new Date().getTime()).toLocaleString(); // 11/16/2015, 11:18:48 PM
new Date(new Date().getTime()).toLocaleTimeString(); // 11:18:48 AM
```

Comment: i dont want current date i just want to convert this created_at:"2016-04-24T18:42:52Z"

Comment: thanks its working but still AM PM missing
actually i am making twitter bot its a nodejs Dyno
it will tweet current date and time in reply to someone
but i am facing timezone problem twitter api gives me US timezone
i want (asia/karachi GMT+5) timezone